# Remove all {} from list type

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, web-scraping, python-requests

hi everyone so i am scraping amazon website,I am getting all 16 links but want to remove the {} part from the newly generated list. Output Provided

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

import time

import pandas as pd


s = HTMLSession()


r = s.get("https://www.amazon.in/s?k=oneplus&page=1")

r.html.render(sleep=1)

t= []


Everything = r.html.find("div.s-include-content-margin.s-border-bottom.s-latency-cf-section")


for e in Everything:

links = e.find("a.a-link-normal.a-text-normal")[0].absolute_links

t.append(links)

print("\n",t)
```

[image: Output]

Comment: "turn every absolute link into a list type" I can't understand what you expect this to mean. Please show an example of what is in the HTML source, and what the value of `t` should be as a result.

Comment: hi i have edited my post with proper output, please can you see, I want to remove the {} part from the list as when i converted it into a List it was <class Set>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You basically are getting a list of sets. In order to convert each element of set into the list element, use `itertools.chain.from_iterable`. [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)

```
from itertools import chain
l = list(chain.from_iterable(t))

# Output
# ['https://www.amazon.in/OnePlus-Nord-Gray-256GB-Storage/dp/B08697WT6D/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=oneplus&qid=1612537850&sr=8-1', 'https://www.amazon.in/OnePlus-Nord-Gray-128GB-Storage/dp/B08695ZSP6/ref=sr_1_2?dchild=1&keywords=oneplus&qid=1612537850&sr=8-2', 'https://www.amazon.in/OnePlus-Bullets-Wireless-Bluetooth-Earphones/dp/B086CSGV2N/ref=sr_1_3?dchild=1&keywords=oneplus&qid=1612537850&sr=8-3', 'https://www.amazon.in/OnePlus-Nord-Marble-256GB-Storage/dp/B0869855B8/ref=sr_1_4?dchild=1&keywords=oneplus&qid=1612537850&sr=8-4', 'https://www.amazon.in/OnePlus-Buds-Z-White/dp/B07XY541GH/ref=sr_1_5?dchild=1&keywords=oneplus&qid=1612537850&sr=8-5', 'https://www.amazon.in/OnePlus-Bullets-Wireless-Bass-Reverb/dp/B08HLTFB33/ref=sr_1_6?dchild=1&keywords=oneplus&qid=1612537850&sr=8-6', 'https://www.amazon.in/OnePlus-Band-Dual-Color-Continuous-Saturation/dp/B07XY9BZPM/ref=sr_1_7?dchild=1&keywords=oneplus&qid=1612537850&sr=8-7', 'https://www.amazon.in/OnePlus-Mirror-Black-128GB-Storage/dp/B085J17VVP/ref=sr_1_8?dchild=1&keywords=oneplus&qid=1612537850&sr=8-8', 'https://www.amazon.in/OnePlus-Glacial-Green-128GB-Storage/dp/B078BNQ318/ref=sr_1_9?dchild=1&keywords=oneplus&qid=1612537850&sr=8-9', 'https://www.amazon.in/OnePlus-Mirror-Black-128GB-Storage/dp/B085J19V4P/ref=sr_1_10?dchild=1&keywords=oneplus&qid=1612537850&sr=8-10', 'https://www.amazon.in/OnePlus-Mirror-Black-128GB-Storage/dp/B085J1CPD1/ref=sr_1_11?dchild=1&keywords=oneplus&qid=1612537850&sr=8-11', 'https://www.amazon.in/OnePlus-Mirror-Black-128GB-Storage/dp/B085J1PFYB/ref=sr_1_12?dchild=1&keywords=oneplus&qid=1612537850&sr=8-12', 'https://www.amazon.in/OnePlus-E501A-Buds-White/dp/B08CVMXPGY/ref=sr_1_13?dchild=1&keywords=oneplus&qid=1612537850&sr=8-13', 'https://www.amazon.in/OnePlus-Bullets-Wireless-Bass-Blue/dp/B08HLSW3Y9/ref=sr_1_14?dchild=1&keywords=oneplus&qid=1612537850&sr=8-14', 'https://www.amazon.in/OnePlus-10000-Charging-Lithium-Polymer/dp/B08HRZ3MXK/ref=sr_1_15?dchild=1&keywords=oneplus&qid=1612537850&sr=8-15', 'https://www.amazon.in/OnePlus-Buds-Z-Gray/dp/B08HLVKCKC/ref=sr_1_16?dchild=1&keywords=oneplus&qid=1612537850&sr=8-16']
```

Comment: you are awesome, it has worked, thanks you so much :) so first append the links to an empty list and then use itertool yes :)

Answer (score 2):

How are you getting a set with one value, just `pop` it. Change the line:

```
links = e.find("a.a-link-normal.a-text-normal")[0].absolute_links
```

To:

```
links = e.find("a.a-link-normal.a-text-normal")[0].absolute_links.pop()
```

Comment: hi i have edited my post with proper output, please can you see, I want to remove the {} part from the list as when i converted it into a List it was <class Set>